# AngularJS adding inputs that represent an array model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple AngularJS questions that I can't get my head around.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OjaooVOQBEETkhaZFbWG?p=preview

HTML;

```
    <div ng-repeat="label in likedLabels">
         <input ng-model="likedLabels[$index]">
    </div>
    {{likedLabels}}
    <button ng-click="addInput()">+add more inputs</button>
```

JS:

```
   $scope.likedLabels = ['']
   $scope.addInput = function(){
     $scope.likedLabels.push('');
   }
```

I'm basically trying to create a user-operated way of adding input boxes and having the content inside linked to a model. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/Mmxhdl9mQeg6fEdc6Bft?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl Nope, I want to literally add input elements on clicking the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use objects rather than primitives in your arrays. Directives like `ng-repeat` create separate child scopes for each repeated item in array.

Due to protoypical inheritance, objects will be passed as reference of original object to the child scope whereas primitives ( strings, booleans etc) won't. Thus there is no data binding of primitives in the scope tree

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in likedLabels">
    <input ng-model="item.label">
</div>
```

JS

```
 $scope.likedLabels = []
  $scope.addInput = function() {
    $scope.likedLabels.push({label: ''});
  }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BLXVXVEzXpltVKUPPbD?p=preview)**</kbd>